# How to check if value of one array is key of another?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP values from array where key is in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904118/php-values-from-array-where-key-is-in-another-array)

As it says in the question.

What I want to know:

```
$xyz = array (
    [0] => 'orange',
    [1] => 'apple'
);

$pqr = array (
    ['orange'] => 'this data'
);
```

Firstly, how to check if the value of one array is a key for another and fetch the data via the link?
I am fine if we use PHP 5.4 or maybe php 5.5 enhanced features for getting the solution for this array thing.

Any help, appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$foo = array('orange', 'apple');    
$bar = array('orange' => 'data');

$result = array_filter($foo, function($value) use ($bar) { return isset($bar[$value]); });

foreach($result as $foobar) {
    echo (isset($bar[$foobar])) ? $bar[$foobar] : NULL; // be on the safe side
    echo $bar[$foobar]; // should be enough
}
```

Comment: woot, that was quick... Let me try

Comment: saw it, I want to return -> 'data'

Comment: edited, and added maybe unnecessary check

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is an default way next to looping over everything:

```
foreach($x in $xyz){
  if(isset($pqe[$x])){ echo $pqe[$x]; }
}
```